# React Call method on *SPECIFIC* props change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a react component that calls a callback function only when a prop changes from false to true. I can't have the parent control the callback directly because I need to pass child state into the callback. I understand I could pull the child state up to the parent, but in trying that, that made my code really messy, so I would like to avoid that if at all possible. In other words:

```
// not proper typescript but I don't care
const MyComponent = ({shouldUpdateState: boolean, updateParentState: Dispatch<CustomState>}): FC => {
    const [someVariableThatExistsInsideThisComponent, useSomeVariableThatExistsInsideThisComponent] = useState<CustomState>(DEFAULT_CUSTOM_STATE)
    // how do I write this line?
    if(shouldUpdateState && reasonForRerender === changeTo(shouldUpdateState)) {
        updateParentState(someVariableThatExistsInsideThisComponent)
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Note that in my case, the method is idempotent, so double calling is not a big concern, but also expensive so I don't want to call it on every rerender if possible

Comment: doing some stuff when a state changes is what an *effect* is all about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Jonas Wilms for this answer. `useEffect` is what I'm looking for. Code looks like this

```
// not proper typescript but I don't care
const MyComponent = ({shouldUpdateState: boolean, updateParentState: Dispatch<CustomState>}): FC => {
    const [someVariableThatExistsInsideThisComponent, useSomeVariableThatExistsInsideThisComponent] = useState<CustomState>(DEFAULT_CUSTOM_STATE)
    useEffect(() => {
        if(shouldUpdateState) {
             updateParentState(someVariableThatExistsInsideThisComponent)
        }
    }, [shouldUpdateState])
...
```

}